# How to securely add an entry into a docker container's /etc/passwd for the uid set with docker's --user option

Tags: docker, dockerfile, fuse

### Problem

For a docker image (alpine based) that is supposed to run as non-root I have two requirements:

1. I have to mount a FUSE filesystem inside the docker container
2. The users of the docker image are able to set the UID/GID of the docker
   user with `docker run --user {uid}:{gid}`

FUSE's `fusermount` command requires a valid entry for the user in `/etc/passwd`, otherwise it won't  mount the filesystem. Given that I don't know the the UID/GID of the user at build time I can't call `adduser` at build time. And I can't do it at runtime either, as the user then doesn't have the appropriate privileges.

### Solutions found

So far I have found two solutions that both feel not appropriate/secure

#### 1. Make /etc/passwd writable

When adding `chmod 555 /etc/passwd` to the Dockerfile I can then do at runtime

```
echo "someuser:x:${my_uid}:$(id -g)::/tmp:/sbin/nologin" >> /etc/passwd
```

This does the job for fusermount. Unfortunately I did not find a way to make change the passwd file back to read-only at runtime and without that I have security concerns that someone might be able to misuse this to gain root rights back. While I could not find a simple way to use the open passwd file for some exploit (while I was able to add/modify password & configurations directly in /etc/passwd for all users and then change users via `login`, alpine did not allow this for user root (neither via `login` nor via `su`). But I guess there are folk out there more clever than me, and somehow the whole solution feels like a quite dirty hack. Does anyone have specific ideas how a writeable passwd file inside a container could be used for getting inappropriate rights inside the container?

#### 2. Replace requirement #2 with two additional environment variables

By introducing DUID and DGID as environment variables and set USER to some newly added non-root user inside the Dockerfile I found a solution with the help of sudo & /etc/sudoers: In a launch script that I use as entrypoint I can call sudo adduser/addgroup for the given DUID/DGID and then launch the actual program with the user specified via `sudo -u someuser someprog`.

Except for the fact that the whole setup became quite ugly, I disliked the fact the user's of my docker image could no longer use the regular `docker run --user` option, as this would break the sudo configuration.